# How to use the bash script for directory structure?

Tags: bash, macos, directory, sh, automator

**The Brief:**
I'm trying to make a directory structure using Automator on mac [Automator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpuGU.png)
and using this bash script

```
mkdir -p "$1/$2/Client_Name_Social_Media/01_January_2020/Design/Deliverables"
```

**The Problem:**
I need to add the Client_name before every directory name. I have many clients, and I don't want to waste my time renaming the directories.

**Ultimate directory structure:**

- Client_Name

  - Client_Name_Social_Media

    - Client_Name_Month

      - Client_Name_Calendars
      - Client_Name_Design

        - Client_Name_OpenFiles
        - Client_Name_Deliverables
      - Client_Name_Campaigns

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this solved my problem:

```
DIR="$1"
CLIENT="$2"
TMONTH="$(date -j +%d_%B_%Y)"

mkdir -p ${DIR}/${CLIENT}/${CLIENT}_Social_Media/${CLIENT}_${TMONTH}/${CLIENT}_Calendars
mkdir -p ${DIR}/${CLIENT}/${CLIENT}_Social_Media/${CLIENT}_${TMONTH}/${CLIENT}_Design/${CLIENT}_OpenFiles
mkdir -p ${DIR}/${CLIENT}/${CLIENT}_Social_Media/${CLIENT}_${TMONTH}/${CLIENT}_Design/${CLIENT}_Deliverables
mkdir -p ${DIR}/${CLIENT}/${CLIENT}_Campaigns
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the client names in an array, and iterate across them in a loop to create the directories. In your example, to create the directories up to `Client_Name_Month` with client names `Client1`, `SomeClient2`, `C3`, you can use:

```
for clname in {"Client1", "SomeClient2", "C3"}
do
    mkdir -p "${cln}/${cln}_Social_Media/${cln}_Month"
done
```

This will create the directories:

```
Client1/Client1_Social_Media/Client1_Month
SomeClient2/SomeClient2_Social_Media/SomeClient2_Month
C3/C3_Social_Media/C3_Month
```

Comment: So just to make sure, i add this script to the automator shell script? and when I enter the client name, it will automatically add the client name to the folders?

Answer (score 0):

As similar to create directories from scratch for a new customer list as stored in `clnames` @GoodDeeds answer the appropriate cli `bash` answer would be:

```
clnames=("Client1" "SomeClient2" "C3")
for cln in "${clnames[@]}"; do
   mkdir -p "./${cln}/${cln}_Social_Media/${cln}_Month/${cln}_Calendars"
   mkdir -p "./${cln}/${cln}_Social_Media/${cln}_Month/${cln}_Design/${cln}_OpenFiles"
   mkdir -p "./${cln}/${cln}_Social_Media/${cln}_Month/${cln}_Design/${cln}_Deliverables"
   mkdir -p "./${cln}/${cln}_Social_Media/${cln}_Month/${cln}_Campaigns"
done
```

Note: this does not work directly in your automator script as written.

If you needed to rename the directory structures recursively of existing an customer named `ClientName` to `JohnSmith` it might look like this

```
find . -depth -name 'ClientName_*' -execdir bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0//ClientName_/JohnSmith_}"' {} \;
```